# .htaccess redirect with variable

Tags: .htaccess

I already have a .htaccess file with the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.site\.com
RewriteRule .* http://site.com/%1 [R]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

What it is doing is taking a page name in the form of page1.site.com and turning that into site.com/page1 in the URL which works. I want the URL to stay looking like page1.site.com while maintaining the current functionality.

Also it currently breaks when a user types in www.page1.site.com...when they type that it should take page1 as the variable and pass it through. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want the PT directive for RewriteRule.  Look for it at: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [PT]